# USB not showing in my PC 17.10

Tags: usb, 17.10

when i type `lsusb` than it shows these devices

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnTDp.png)
In here, `A-DATA Technologo Co., LTd.` is my `pendrive` and

and `Samsung Electronics co., Ltd Galaxy` is my `phone`.

both are not showing in files  -

OS: `ubuntu 17.10`

PC:  `dell inspiron 3542`.

what is the solution ??

Comment: Did you `mount` the USB hardware? If not, look up how.

Comment: @user535733 mount worked for pendrive but it does't worked for android phone. What should I do for android ??